# How to force Haskell to check lengths of lists?

Tags: haskell, types, type-level-computation

We can define function `f` and `g` like this:

```
f :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
f = (++)

g :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
g = zipWith (+)
```

Both `f` and `g` take two lists as parameters and return a new list, but they are different: `f` returns a longer list whose length is the sum of the inputs', meanwhile `g` processes lists with the same length. How to figure this out to Haskell?

Comment: Actually `g` will have type `Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`, so it doesn't work for arbitrary lists, only for lists of numbers. Besides, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @chris OK, I can force `f :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`, so there's no difference between the two type declaration. My point is, Haskell will not complaint for both `f (g [1..10] [11..20]) [21..30]` and `g (f [1..10] [11..20]) [21..30]`, but I hope Haskell can give a warning or error for the latter one (when compiling, not runtime).

Comment: @SaltyEgg That would require tracking the length parameter in the type. It is possible to clumsily do this in Haskell, but you have a fairly hard limitation to that in that only the very most modern GHC has the beginnings of type-level computation such as integer addition. You'd much more likely want to do this is Idris or Agda.

Comment: @chris think of it as `zipWith (,)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want is to encode the length of lists into the type system. In other words, encode natural numbers in the type system and operations on them. This is possible, although it involves some type trickery. There are libraries to achieve this, one of them [tagged-list](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-list-1.1/docs/Data-List-Tagged.html). `TaggedList` is tagged with its length as a type-level natural number. Then the types of your functions would look like

```
import Data.List.Tagged as T
import TypeLevel.NaturalNumber.Operations (Plus)

f :: TaggedList n a -> TaggedList m a -> TaggedList (Plus n m) a
f = T.append

g :: (Num a) => TaggedList n a -> TaggedList n a -> TaggedList n a
g x = T.zipf (T.map (+) x) -- apparently the Tagged library lacks zipWith
                           -- so we implement it ourselves
```

which gives clear distinction of what happens with the length of the lists.

See also [Type arithmetic](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you want your `g` to check that the lists are the same length first before performing the operation.  That's relatively easy:

```
-- Correct type signature as @chris mentioned
g :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
g xs ys = if length xs == length ys then zipWith (+) xs ys else error "Incompatible lists"
```

However, this is a really bad way to throw errors, you'd be better off using the `Maybe` monad:

```
g :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
g xs ys = if length xs == length ys then Just $ zipWith (+) xs ys else Nothing
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the length to be expressed in the type like Idris Vectors, not just checked at runtime.

Comment: @Lee Yes, I hope Haskell can complaint when compiling the code if I misused `g`.

Comment: @SaltyEgg Haskell doesn't work that way, how can it possibly know if you've passed in lists of different sizes at compile time?  Most of my data comes from external hardware or large files that don't even necessarily exist when the program is compiled, so there's no way it could check code like that.  Haskell lists are not vectors, they're more like linked lists, so maybe you could try looking at vectors from the `Repa` library?  I believe they have their size encoded into the type, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I checked, and Repa encodes the shape of the vector (1D, 2D, 3D, etc), not the size.  You _could_ use type level `Nats`, but that gets ugly and slow fast.  It's usually best not to use the type system to do computations, there are much more elegant ways to express what you want to do with runtime error handling.

Comment: Haskell doesn't work that way? Default lists don't work that way. See the top answer.

Comment: @JMCF125 "Haskell doesn't work that way, how can it possibly know if you've passed in lists of different sizes at compile time?"  I clearly specified lists, not other types.  My next comment also elaborated on using different types.  Petr certainly has a different answer, but he also had the advantage of answering after SaltyEgg clarified that he wanted this behavior at compile time, as his initial question that I attempted to answer did not specify this.

Comment: «Haskell doesn't work that way, how can it possibly know if you've passed in lists of different sizes at compile time?»: using different list types! AFAIK, "list" is not a reserved keyword for "Haskell default list". Besides, his question didn't make sense at runtime; this is not an answer.

Comment: @JMCF125 OP also used the list type in his example, so "list" was pretty clear to me from context.  Since there was potentially useful information in my answer and the comments I chose not to delete it, even though it is not directly relevant to the actual problem, which was answered perfectly by Petr after OP further explained his question.

Comment: You're right in what you say, thus I won't downvote, but the OP knows less about his own problem than you, so he probably didn't think of another list type as well.